# $W^{2,p}$-estimates for Neumann boundary condition to Poisson equation

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, regularity

Consider the following Poisson-Neumann problem in a lipschitz bounded domain $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^3$:

$-\Delta u=F,\quad \partial_n u\restriction_{\partial\Omega}=0$.

Here $F\in L^p(\Omega)$.

I want to know whether one can find solutions $u\in W^{2,p}(\Omega)$ and an estimate like $||u||_{2,p}\leq C ||F||_p$ or $||u||_{2,p}\leq C [||F||_p+||u||_2]$ or similar things by regularity theory, interpolation etc. Also, I want to know in what sense regularity of $\Omega$ comes into play concerning the constant $C$ above, i.e. is this constant explicitely depending on the lipschitz character of $\Omega$ or are just the measure or the diameter of $\Omega$ important?

We can always have in mind the special case $F=\nabla\cdot b$ for some $b\in L^p(\Omega)^3$.

I already know that such things hold for $p=2$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the mean $\partial_n u|_{\partial\Omega }=0 $ in weak sense？

Comment: The mean ist $\int_{\partial \Omega} u\cdot \partial_n\phi =0$ for any test function $\phi\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^3)^3$

Comment: For sure you need some norm of $u$ on the right-hand side, since $u+k$ is also a solution for any constant $k$.